# Binary tree node ratio calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binary-tree

I have a user hierarchy in binary tree format (because one user can add max 2 users). below is a sample structure

[image: User hierarchy]

**Problems**

1. Weekly I have to calculate how many users have been added in ratio of `2:1` or `1:2` under logged in user to make payment. `2:1` ratio (highlighted in RED) means `User A` added `User B1` & `User B2`, and `User B1` added `User C1`. Similarly in `1:2` ratio (highlighted in yellow), `User B2` has `User D1 & D2` but only `User D1` has `User E1 & E2` so it fulfills `1:2` ratio.
2. So if more user is added then we have to obviously skip user already calculated in above ratio in first week. And this we have to keep in mind while calculating payment for the week.

**Problem in other word**

Weekly I have to make payment to users directly or indirectly referred by me or by members in my child hierarchy. Condition of payment is `2:1 or 1:2` and each member can refer 2 direct members.

In User table I have `UserId` as identity and `ParentId` column as self refernce to keep track of parent of member. I am ready to alter my table structure if required.

Comment: So... do you have a particular problem, or are you just trying to push your work onto us?

Comment: Actually I am not getting how to solve this ratio problem, I have been trying this for last 2 weeks but no success. I consulted my friends too but no luck...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic.  Are you saying there is a 2:1 relationship with B nodes (B1 and B2) to C nodes (C1)?  If so then isn't there a 2:2 relationship of D nodes to E nodes and a 1:1 of C to F?  In fact the only 1:2 relationship seems to be A nodes to B nodes.

Comment: @juharr : Your perception is wrong, logic is if I referred A & B and if A or B refer any one member (for example C) then I will get payment. So here 2:1 (A,B:C) ratio applies. I hope its clear.

Comment: You say that there is 1:2 ratio because B2 has 2 child nodes with only one of them having 2 further child nodes. So why there is 2:1 ratio in A? A's second child (B2) has also two child nodes. Perhaps try to rephrase your problem in tree terms (parent, child nodes) and using more precise notation to define the concept of the "ratio".